# Using a BASH script variable into an executed command

Tags: bash, variables

Can someone please help with this because I can't seem to find a solution. I have the following script that works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Checks the number of lines in the userdomains file

NUM=`awk 'END {print NR}' /etc/userdomains.hristian`;

echo $NUM


#Prints out a particular line from the file (should work with $NUM eventually)

USER=`sed -n 4p /etc/userdomains.hristian`

echo $USER


#Edits the output so that only the username is left

USER2=`echo $USER | awk '{print $NF}'`

echo $USER2
```

However, when I substitute the 4 on line 12 with the variable $NUM, like this, it doesn't work:

```
USER=`sed -n $NUMp /etc/userdomains.hristian`
```

I tried a number of different combinations of quotes and ${}, however none of them seem to work because I'm a BASH newbie. Help please :)

Comment: You didn't try all the combinations: `USER=\`sed -n ${NUM}p /etc/userdomains.hristian\``. As a side note: _don't use upper case variable names in Bash!_ here you're doing it wrong: `USER` is very likely a variable set and used by your system; you might have a clash sooner or later! As a bonus note: don't use backticks, use `$(...)` instead: `USER=$(sed -n ${NUM}p /etc/userdomains.hristian)`.

Comment: Are you trying to print the last line of your file? if so, `tail -n1 /etc/userdomains.hristian` will do the job more efficiently.

Comment: The last field of the last line, apparently. The shortest way to do that is probably `awk 'END { print $NF }' /etc/userdomains.hristian`, although using `tail -n1 /etc/userdomains.hristian | awk '{ print $NF }'` will be more efficient for large files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you've already tried but this works for me:

```
$ cat out
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
$ num=4
$ a=`sed -n ${num}p out`
$ echo "$a"
line 4
```

To be clear, the issue here is that you need to separate the expansion of `$num` from the `p` in the sed command. That's what the curly braces do.
Note that I'm using lowercase variable names. Uppercase ones should be be reserved for use by the shell. I would also recommend using the more modern `$()` syntax for command substitution:

```
a=$(sed -n "${num}p" out)
```

The double quotes around the sed command aren't necessary but they don't do any harm. In general, it's a good idea to use them around expansions.

Presumably the script in your question is a learning exercise, which is why you have done all of the steps separately. For the record, you could do the whole thing in one go like this:

```
awk 'END { print $NF }' /etc/userdomains.hristian
```

In the `END` block, the values from the last line in the file can still be accessed, so you can print the last field directly.

Comment: Oh my, it works. Thank you very much for the information and the recommendation. Note taken.

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to evaluate the variable `$NUMp` rather than `$NUM`. Try this instead:

```
USER=`sed -n ${NUM}p /etc/userdomains.hristian`
```